# Swift 3 - UITableView is cut off in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, autolayout

i have a problem with my tableview which is in a scrollview. The table is cut off at the end.

[image: cut off]

This is my storyboard (scrolling is disabled for the table). The button is just a placeholder for some content in my real app:

[image: storyboard]

This is the table-class (I know its from the question from yesterday I just can't figure the problem out):

```
class Table: UITableView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    let sections: [String] = ["Section 1", "Section 2", "Section 3"]
    let s1Data: [String] = ["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3"]
    let s2Data: [String] = ["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3"]
    let s3Data: [String] = ["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3"]

    var sectionData: [Int: [String]] = [:]

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        delegate = self
        dataSource = self

        register(UINib(nibName: "Cell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        sectionData = [0:s1Data, 1:s2Data, 2:s3Data]

        rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        estimatedRowHeight = 96.0

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)
        -> Int {
            return (sectionData[section]?.count)!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int)
        -> String? {
            return sections[section]
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

        return cell!

    }

}
```

The cell itself has a height of 340 and in the table should be three of them.

The ViewController has a constraint to the height of the table and the table itself. I read something about this solution on stackoverflow. When I set a breakpoint at the constraint-constant-set the height is about 1000 so this is correct at this point.:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var table: Table!

    override func viewDidLoad() { 
        super.viewDidLoad()  
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        tableHeight.constant = table.contentSize.height
    }

}
```

I tried different suggestions how to get rid of the probelm. But somehow I miss something. Has someone maybe an advice for me.

Comment: Did your problem has been solved?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you have not set a constraint from the bottom of your tableview to the bottom of it's superview (the View in the scrollview). If so, then the View will not resize to fit all the table in it

Answer (score 0):

- i have set all the constraint as per your requirements
  , i have installed **top , left , right and bottom** constraint of
  ScrollView and ContentView and give **equal width and height** of
  contentView to Main View and so the scrollview will automatically get
  bigger as its contents size.
- if you want to scroll only ScrollView not your tableView then in this
  case you can give a fixed height Constraint of TableView , create a **@IBOutlet** of NSLayoutConstraint of that fixed height Constarint and update its
  constant by calculating the all row heights!

**1st approach :**

- Remove fixed height Constraint
- try to give a bottom constraint of your tableView to ScrollView (not
  to contentView - (a UIView that is inside a ScrollView) )

**2nd approach :**

Try this one in viewDidLoad method:

**Give Padding to tableView From Bottom:**

here i gave a 20.0 fixed padding to tableView bottom , you can  give as your requirements.

```
yourTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 20.0, right: 0.0)
```

here is the demo link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-VsxWuYK8apODhXSnc1aVM5djQ/view

Comment: What error you got @SohilR.Memon , and tell me which constraint you give to tableView.

Comment: Are you familiar with AutoLayout? `UITableView` should get fixed height because inside it has own `UIScrollView` and so it will clash for the `contentSize`. You can try out at your own!

Comment: @SohilR.Memon i am very familiar with AutoLayout rather then yours , and i have created my own demo , its work wonderfull with me.!

Comment: Send me demo link pls via dropbox! I need to learn how you have done that!

Comment: @SohilR.Memon  here is the link : download it and run it 

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-VsxWuYK8apODhXSnc1aVM5djQ

Comment: The BlackColorView is ScrollView , and RedColorView is TableView , you can see its scroll very well from top to bottom.!

Comment: Remove the Equal Height of `UIView` because you have already told that your `UIScrollView` will be equal to screen size. What if my `UiTableView` is bigger and I want the `UIScrollView` bigger?

Comment: Where? This one? `yourTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 20.0, right: 0.0)`

Comment: what ? cant understand your question ?

Comment: I mean what if I want to increase the `UIScrollView` height depending on my `UITableView`. What you have done, you have given fixed height to to your `SuperView`. But as I said remove the fixed height and I want the `UIScrollView` height based on my content inside `UIScrollView`. I Want the equal height to `SuperView` then I just would have taken the `UIView` and achieve what you have done!

Comment: you want to scroll tableView or not ? i have replied for both condition ..
1st : dynamically increase the size of ScrollView based on its contents and Fixed height of TableView.. But it seems you cant understand what i have done..!

Comment: it seems you dont want to scroll TableView , you only want to scroll ScrollView with its content size .. then apply the logic ::---  you can give a fixed height Constraint of TableView , create a @IBOutlet of NSLayoutConstraint of that fixed height Constarint and update its constant by calculating the all row heights! ,  I have already discussed this things in answer but it seems you cant understand what i want to share with you.!

Comment: You answer - dynamically increase the size of ScrollView based on its contents and Fixed height of TableView - this is what the user want!

In Ques he clearly mention  - This is my storyboard (scrolling is disabled for the table). The button is just a placeholder for some.

Comment: and so I told - Removing fixed height Constraint - Will give an error. Try it out! :P

Comment: @SohilR.Memon , both are not possible , why are you not understanding , its not possible because TableView has its own ScrollView , in this case you have to go with one option , equal width and height constraint will help us to calculate scrollview's content Size , how ? we gave a top , left , right and bottom constraint of ScrollView to its superView..! and so the main SuperView will increase as scrollView increase.!

Comment: It is possible! Leave it!

Comment: yes possible , but it doesn't look good because you have scrolling both scrollview (Main ScrollView and TableView's ScrollView) , you can try it with your project.. All the best .! leave it .